# Getting background color as well when I transparent the background color

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am trying to make background of a tkinter label widget transparent. But I am still seeing some background color which is making it dirty.

**CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("120x30+1000+550")

label = tk.Label(root, text='Python', bg='white', fg='red', font=('Courier', 25))
label.pack()

root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

root.mainloop()
```

I does transparent the label but I can see some unnecessary white colors behind the text.

[image: White color behind the text]

**Whats wrong am I doing?**

Comment: That's not a problem with Tkinter Label it has to do with the image you using.

Comment: text may have anti-aliasing which may create mix of red and white color - so it is not pure white color, and not pure red color.

Comment: maybe if you use `bg` which is more similar to red color then mix of colors will look better and you will not see it.

Comment: @furas Actually my background is transparent. The background in the above picture is actually the screenshot of command prompt to make you all visible the white color.

Comment: `-transparentcolor` doesn't works on my Linux but I assume that tkinter first creates white background and draws red text with anti-aliasing which creates pixels with mixed color - red and white - so they are not pure white. And later system/wm (wm = windows manager) removes only pure white pixels to create transparent background. For you pixels seems white but for computer are not ideal white and it doesn't remove them. if you use `bg` similar to red then for you they will look like red and you will no see this problem.

Comment: @furas Thank you very much using similar to red color fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

**As @furas told:**

> tkinter first creates white background and draws red text with anti-aliasing which creates pixels with mixed color - red and white - so they are not pure white. And later system/wm (wm = windows manager) removes only pure white pixels to create transparent background. For you pixels seems white but for computer are not ideal white and it doesn't remove them. if you use bg similar to red

So, I changed `bg='white'` to similar color to red which is `bg='#fc0000'` which solved the problem

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("120x30+1000+550")

label = tk.Label(root, text='Python', bg='#fc0000', fg='red', font=('Courier', 25))
label.pack()

root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", '#fc0000')
```

**Thank you very much `furas`**